# How do I get information on installed third party update?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a name of a third party application that has installed updates on a machine. Say, that name is "Adobe Reader".
When I open "Programs And Features" and click on "View installed updates", I can see a line with info on update installed (see attached pic).

However, it seems that `WUApiLib's IUpdateSearcher.QueryHistory` only returns information on Windows Updates and Hotfixes, not 3rd-party apps.

```
using WUApiLib;

var updateSession = new UpdateSession();
var updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
var count = updateSearcher.GetTotalHistoryCount();
var history = updateSearcher.QueryHistory(0, count);
string result = "";

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    result += history[i].Title + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

And the `result` does not contain anything on Adobe at all.

What am I missing?

[image: Installed Adobe Reader Update]

Comment: Well that's because Windows Update doesn't update Adobe products.

Comment: @stuartd any info on how to get update info on Adobe products?

Comment: Adobe Acrobat and Reader use the Windows Installer, which [has it's own API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372860(v=vs.85).aspx).  (I believe other Adobe products such as Photoshop use Adobe's own installer technology, which may or may not use the Windows Installer under the hood.)

Comment: Incidentally, if I remember rightly IUpdateSearcher.QueryHistory will only show Windows updates that were installed via Windows Update.  Updates that were preinstalled or installed manually won't be included.

Comment: Why do you need this anyway?

Comment: @stuartd i have a farm of servers that all have some 3-rd party app that does distributed calculations. At times the app gets updated (manually or via push from the vendor), I need to make sure all servers run the same  version of the app, otherwise the results are not valid.
I can see the updates with app version and other info in the "View installed updates" window.
I have a small windows service on every machine that can be queried via HTTP from single control node. And I want that service to be able to get that latest patch version info.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks for the info, I'll look into it.

Comment: The usual shortcut in this situation is to get the information from the registry, specifically the Uninstall key(s).  Using the API is more correct, but using the registry is significantly simpler.

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes, that seems to be the way to go